# Is the spectral fractional Sobolev norm equivalent to other norms (e.g. Gagliardo...)?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

Let $s \in (0, 1)$ and $\Omega$ be a bounded subdomain of $\mathbb R^n$ with polygonal/polyhedral boundary. Let $\Delta$ be the Laplace-Dirichlet operator on $\Omega$ (i.e. the Laplace operator with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions). We consider the spectrum of $\Delta$ on $\Omega$ given by the sets of eigenfunctions and eigenvalues $(\psi_{i})_{i}$ and $(\lambda_{i})_{i}$ respectively.

Now we introduce the "spectral" fractional Sobolev space as $$\dot H^s := \left\{ v \in L^2(\Omega), \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda_i^s v_i^2 < \infty \right\},$$ where $v_i = \int_{\Omega} v \psi_i$, and its natural norm $$||v||_{\dot H^s}^2 := \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda_i^s v_i^2.$$
The space $\dot H^s$ is actually equal to the "standard" fractional order Sobolev space $H^s_0$ defined by the mean of real interpolation when $s>1/2$, it is equal to the Lions-Magenes space $H^{1/2}_{00}$ when $s=1/2$ and it is equal to the fractional Sobolev space $H^s$ for $s<1/2$ (boundary conditions are meaningless in that case).

But what about the norm $||\cdot||_{\dot H^s}$ ? Is it equivalent to other usual norms for $H^s_0$, $H^{1/2}_{00}$ or $H^s$?

Comment: You can use the [contact us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, so that you can freely edit your question.

Comment: It seems that you have essentially answered you own question in the paragraph just before last... Could you maybe formulate, once again, what, precisely, you are asking?

Comment: I suspect the OP meant, when writing "The space $\dot{H}^s$ is actually equal...." that the equality is of the underlying sets and not necessarily of the norms; in which case the question would parse. @AndréHenriques  (Though it is not clear to me how one may even go about proving the sets are equal without also proving equivalence of norms for things like this.)

Comment: Thank you for your responses @AndréHenriques and WillieWong. WillieWong you have a very good point mentioning that the equality of spaces is very likely proved through norm equivalence. However, the only references I've found on this spaces equality just say "It is well known that..." and do not cite anything.
So in fact my question is actually: do you know any reference where this equality of spaces is established ?
I'll edit my question.

Comment: @BubbleDopple, please do not use multiple usernames. Furthermore, using the one with which you have posted the question gives you the right to comment on your own posts even if you do not have the required minimum of 50 reputation points (that allows you to freely comment anywhere).

Comment: I think at least part of the story is explained in https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3606 and references cited in there. Your spectral Sobolev space is the same as the form domain of the Navier fractional laplacian in that article, and denoted there as $Dom(Q^N_s)$.

Comment: Thank you @WillieWong !